# Do small cumulants imply that a distribution is well-approximated by a Gaussian?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, cumulants

Suppose I know of all the cumulants $\{\kappa_n\}$ of some probability distribution. Is there any result of the form:

> Suppose the cumulants $\{\kappa_n\}$ of a probability distribution converge to zero "sufficiently quickly". Then the distribution can be closely approximated by $\mathcal{N}(\kappa_1,\kappa_2)$

It seems that if $\kappa_3=\kappa_4=\dots=0$, then the distribution in question *is* $\mathcal{N}(\kappa_1,\kappa_2)$.

(As an aside, it seems that the converse isn't true. For a Poisson distribution, $\kappa_n=\lambda$ for all $n$, but for large $\lambda$, the Poisson distribution can be well-approximated by the normal distribution.)

Comment: Your condition cannot be correct (as you have noticed yourself). The argument is that if $X$ is normal distributed, so is $Y = \lambda X$ with any $\lambda >0$. So the condition on the cumulants should be something like $(k_n)^{1/n} \ll \sqrt{k_2}$ ($n\geq 3$), in order that the distribution is almost normal.

Comment: The condition $(\kappa_n)^{1/n}\ll\sqrt{\kappa_2}$ make sense--is there any sort of analytical evidence to support it that you're aware of?

Comment: I added some evidence in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the wrong condition when the distribution is (almost) normal.

You should think about this analogously to some of the proofs of the central limit theorem. Given that $X$ is distributed with finite mean $$\mu = \kappa_1 = \operatorname{E}(X) $$
and finite variance
$$ \sigma^2 =\kappa_2 = \operatorname{Var}(X) >0 \;.$$
We should look at the distribution of the shifted and normalized variable
$$ Y = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}.$$

Let us denote the cumulants of $Y$ by $k_n$.
By some elementary properties of the cumulant, we have that
$$ \kappa_n = \sigma^n k_n, \qquad n\geq 2 \;.$$

In particular, we have that $k_1=0$ and $k_2=1$. Now the distribution of $Y$ is (almost) normal if
$$ k_n \ll 1, \qquad n\geq 3.$$

By linearity, the distribution of $X$ is (almost) normal if
$$ \kappa_n \ll \sigma^n = \kappa_2^{n/2},\qquad n  \geq3 \;. $$

**Example:**

For the Poisson distribution, we have $k_n = \lambda$. The condition that the distribution is almost normal reads
$$ \lambda \ll \lambda^{n/2}, \qquad n\geq 3$$
which is valid for $\lambda \gg 1$.

Comment: You assert “$Y$ is (almost) normal if $k_n\ll1$.” How do we know that’s true?